# Loading screen using React + Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Right now I have a react app using redux. I've created a component that works as a Form to create customers. Like this:

```
import { createCustomer } from "../../actions";

class CustomerCreate extends React.Component {

  state = {
    submitting: false
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ submitting: false });
  }

  submitData = (data) => {
    this.setState({ submitting: true });
    this.props.createCustomer(data);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.state.submitting ? <LoadingScreen /> : null}
        {this.props.error ? <ErrorMessage message={this.props.error}/> : null}
        <FormContainer
        ...
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ customerData }) => {
  return {
    error: customerData.error
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { createCustomer })(
  CustomerCreate
);
```

This works 'fine'. Basically **componentWillReceiveProps** will be called every time something happens(error, ok) so I will know when to remove the LoadingScreen. The problem is that **componentWillReceiveProps** is throwing a warning(saying that shouldn't be used) and based on redux documentation this is marked as an anti-pattern.

I know one solution could be not using redux here. Changing submitData with the axions call and put the setState there. But I used it like this because one of the error messages could be: **SESSION EXPIRED** or **INVALID JWT TOKEN** so I need to resend the webpage to the Login Screen.

Another way I can think is calling in the action a dispatch to set isSubmitting state. Something like this:

```
export const createCustomer = (data) => {
  /* IS THIS VALID? */
  dispatch({ type: CUSTOMER_SUBMITTING });
  return async function (dispatch) {
    try {
      const response = await services.post("/api/customer", data, buildHeader());
      dispatch({ type: CUSTOMER_CREATED, payload: response.data });
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({ type: CUSTOMER_ERROR, payload: err });
    }
  };
};
```

And instead of using **state.isSubmitting** I will use a **props.isSubmitting**. But i'm not sure if calling two dispath like this is valid/correct.

**So, my question is:** How can I implement a state/props that is set to true when I'm submitting and is set to false when the axios call is finished(by some error or just OK).

Comment: I suggest you take a look at `redux-saga`.

Comment: `componentDidUpdate(prevState, prevProps, snapshot)` can't work for you? When the prop from redux updates you can compare it against the previous prop value and set your submitting state to false.

Comment: Base on my experience, I usually apply the second solution you mentioned - add `isSubmitting` to redux. I believe handle all the request status (isFecthing, isError, data...) in redux is easier to manage. And lots of packages for redux can help you do this with less code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle function. Add a form processing success action and state in redux and map it to props.

```
import { createCustomer } from "../../actions";

class CustomerCreate extends React.Component {

  state = {
    submitting: false
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevState, prevProps) {
    // If a new error comes in and was previously "falsey" set submitting false
    if (prevProps.error !== this.props.error && this.props.error) {
      this.setState({ submitting: false });
    }
    // Similar check for form success
  }

  submitData = (data) => {
    this.setState({ submitting: true });
    this.props.createCustomer(data);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.state.submitting ? <LoadingScreen /> : null}
        {this.props.error ? <ErrorMessage message={this.props.error}/> : null}
        <FormContainer
        ...
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ customerData }) => {
  return {
    error: customerData.error,
    success: /* some success value from redux */
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { createCustomer })(
  CustomerCreate
);
```

Or as a functional component, use state and effect hooks:

```
import { createCustomer } from "../../actions";

const CustomerCreate ({ createCustomer, error, success }) => {

  const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error || success) setSubmitting(false);
  }, [error, success]);

  submitData = (data) => {
    setSubmitting(true);
    createCustomer(data);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {submitting ? <LoadingScreen /> : null}
      {error ? <ErrorMessage message={error}/> : null}
      <FormContainer
        ...
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ customerData }) => ({
  error: customerData.error,
  success: /* some success value from redux */
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { createCustomer })(
  CustomerCreate
);
```

Comment: The thing is that componentDidUpdate is called after render, so calling a setState there will call another render. Could be this a performance issue?

Comment: Not really, no. I say "not really" as for most use cases there won't be performance issues unless your code is doing not very smart things, applying react anti-patterns, or calling super heavy or high-latency functions. Have you tried it? Usually go for the easy straight forward solution until you actually notice performance issues. I'd say a component rendering an extra time or two would not fall into the category of a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used this blog post with some changes, to separate loading states to actual actions:

https://medium.com/stashaway-engineering/react-redux-tips-better-way-to-handle-loading-flags-in-your-reducers-afda42a804c6

I created a loadingReducer like this:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
}

const loadingReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    const { type } = action;
    const matches = /(.*)_(DELETE|REQUEST|SUCCESS|FAILURE)/.exec(type);

    // not a *_REQUEST / *_SUCCESS /  *_FAILURE actions, so we ignore them
    if (!matches) return state;
    const [, requestName, requestState] = matches;
    return {
        ...state,
        // Store whether a request is happening at the moment or not
        // e.g. will be true when receiving GET_TODOS_REQUEST
        //      and false when receiving GET_TODOS_SUCCESS / GET_TODOS_FAILURE
        [requestName]: requestState === 'REQUEST',
        [requestName + '_DELETE']: requestState === 'DELETE',
    };
};

export default loadingReducer;
```

Then created the function loadingSelector:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

export const createLoadingSelector = (actions) => (state) => {
    // returns true only when all actions is not loading
    return _(actions)
        .some((action) => _.get(state, action));
};
```

And then created a component that change status based on that reducer:

```
class LoadingScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {
        if (!this.props.isLoading)
            return null;
        return (
            <Backdrop
                className={this.props.classes.backdrop}
                open={true}
            >
                <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
            </Backdrop>
        )
    }


}

const loadingListSelector = createLoadingSelector(['CUSTOMERS']);

const mapStateToProps = ({ loading }) => {
    return {
        isLoading: loadingListSelector(loading)
    };
};
```